# User friendly URL-s with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a PHP project where the page URL-s have the following format:

item.php?productid=7816 
about.php?pageid=2

Is it possible to bring those URL-s to a more user friendly format like this:

items/item_name [or page title]
pages/page_name [or page title]

I know that I can do that with mod_rewrite but have no clues how to do that, how to replace the parameters, etc. with a text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
```

then add

```
RewriteRule PATTERN DESTINATION FLAGS
```

Where Pattern can be any Regex Pattern to match. In Destination you can use Capture Groups from the Pattern. i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9_-]+/([0-9]+)\.html$ show.php?article=$1
```

Where "$1" is what was matched in the parentheses "([0-9]+)"

then I would rewrite your scripts to accept names instead of ids.